# why my firebase listener duplicate the record

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

in my project i'm try to implement a social app including a friends request using cloud firebase

I can't find a solution to avoid the fire base listener duplicate the record!

at the first opening, the list is correct and update, but if for any reason I add a friends the listener duplicate the record.

if I check my database Firestore the record is only one there is no double record.

if I exit and go back to the view all the record are ok.

here a picture of what happen when I add friends.

[image]

I attach my part of my code:

```
func testUpdatePendingUser(userLoggato: UserModel, utenteADDED: @escaping (UserModel)->(), vettoreUser: @escaping ([UserModel])->()) {
        db.collection("user").document(userLoggato.userID).collection("pendingFriends")
            
            .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: false) { documentSnapshot, error in
                var arrayUtentiStart = [UserModel]()
                guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else { return }
                snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { (documentChange) in
                    switch documentChange.type {
                    case .added :
                        debugPrint("add")
                        let dict = documentChange.document.data()
                        let name = dict["name"] as? String ?? "na name"
                        let surname = dict["surname"] as? String ?? "na name"
                        let email = dict["email"] as? String ?? "na name"
                        let userLevel = dict["adminLevel"] as? String ?? "unable to get admin level"
                        let idUser = dict["userID"] as? String ?? "no ID"
                        let position1 = dict["position"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                        let position2 = dict["position2"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                        let vote = dict["vote"] as? Int ?? 0
                        self.downloadImageForAdmin(userID: idUser) { (urlImage) in
                            let utente = UserModel(name: name, surname: surname, email: email, userID: idUser, adminLevel: userLevel, immagine: urlImage, position: position1, position2: position2, vote: vote)
                            utenteADDED(utente)
                            arrayUtentiStart.append(utente)
                            vettoreUser(arrayUtentiStart)
                        }
                    case .modified :
                        debugPrint("mod")
                    case .removed :
                        debugPrint("rem")
                        
                        
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

this to be use on the contentView

```
 func newPendinguser(userLoggato: UserModel){
        usersPendingNEW = []
        testUpdatePendingUser(userLoggato: userLoggato, utenteADDED: { (utenteCambiato) in
            if !self.usersPendingNEW.isEmpty { // case is not empty  , guess problem is here!!
                self.usersPendingNEW.append(utenteCambiato)
            }
        }) { (vettoreIniziale) in
            if self.usersPendingNEW.isEmpty{ // first view appear
                self.usersPendingNEW = vettoreIniziale
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will be duplicate your data.

```
utenteADDED(utente) 

arrayUtentiStart.append(utente) 

vettoreUser(arrayUtentiStart)
```

you design utenteADDED(utente) run when first time init, but when you have data in array, that code still run.

Check **first run** before run this code:

```
utenteADDED(utente)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the array which is presenting the view and then assign the list received via listener